# An oriented curve

Tags: differential-geometry

> An oriented curve has a unique arc length parameterization inducing
>   the given orientation.

If I let $C$ be a curve parameterized by arc length by $\alpha: [0, p]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ how can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had another arclength parametrization $\beta$, then it would have the same domain $[0,p]$ (since $p$ is the length of the curve). Because $\alpha,\beta$ are arclength parametrizations, they are both diffeomorphisms of $[0,p]$ onto their common image; so we have $\alpha = \beta \circ f$ for $f=\beta^{-1} \circ \alpha:[0,p] \to [0,p]$ a diffeomorphism fixing the endpoints. Use $|\alpha'| = |\beta'| = 1$ to conclude that $f = \operatorname{id}$.

Comment: Is there another term for "diffeomorphism" because I have never heard it before?

Comment: @Lays: a function is a diffeomorphism onto its image if it is smooth, injective and has smooth inverse. In this case this last condition just means the derivative is nowhere zero.

Comment: Ah, so another term I can replace "diffeomorphism" will be a "regular curve"?

Comment: @Lays: "regular curve with no self-intersection". As written my argument requires that the curve has no self-intersections, but this should not actually be necessary... I'm unsure on exactly what assumptions we need to conclude that $\alpha = \beta \circ f$ for a smooth $f$.

Comment: Gotcha, "regular curve with no self-intersection" cleared it up for me because we literally talk about no self intersections in the next topic after this. I should go look it up. Thanks!

Comment: @Lays: no problem. After a little more thought I think that the existence of such an $f$ is pretty much the definition of "$\alpha$ and $\beta$ parametrize the same curve" - otherwise you could e.g. go around a circle once with $\alpha$ but twice with $\beta$, resulting in two parametrized curves of different arclength but with the same image.